# Creating 3D Polygon geometry with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, 3d, polygon-creation

I'm trying to add a new feature in a `PolygonZ` gpkg layer with Python code.

I have a list of 3D points (`QgsPoint`), but I don't understand how to create a geometry from this list of `QgsPoint`. Using `QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY` doesn't work because I want to keep the 3D points, not the 2D points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either

```py
from qgis.core import (QgsPolygon, QgsLineString, QgsPoint)

# From a Python list
points = [[0.0, 10.0, 3.0], [5.0, 8.0, 4.0], [9.0, 5.0, 1.0], [0, 10, 3.0]]
poly3d = QgsPolygon(QgsLineString([QgsPoint(*point) for point in points]))
```

or

```py
from qgis.core import (QgsPolygon, QgsLineString, QgsPoint)

# We create manually list of 3D points but you can take/create
# it from your existing 3D point layer
list_of_points = [QgsPoint(0.0, 10.0, 3.0), QgsPoint(5.0, 8.0, 4.0), QgsPoint(9.0, 5.0, 1.0), QgsPoint(0, 10, 3.0)]
poly3d = QgsPolygon(QgsLineString(list_of_points))
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks

Comment: Option `rings=[]` was not needed. Removed... Also accept the answer, plz. Thanks